# opencv warpPerspective parameter count

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

In my script I have the following code:

```
src = numpy.array(cornersSheet, numpy.float32)
dst = numpy.array(cornersDesired, numpy.float32)
transform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src,dst)
finished = cv2.warpPerspective(img, transform, img.shape)
```

Python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./script.py", line 138, in <module>
    finished = cv2.warpPerspective(img, transform, img.shape)
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

but according to documentation:

```
    Python: cv2.warpPerspective(src, M, dsize[, dst[, flags[, borderMode[, borderValue]]]]) → dst
```

three parameters are OK. I have the same issue with `cv2.warpAffine`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Problem solved. `img.shape` returns tuple with 3 elements, warpPerspective expects tuple with 2.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
finished = cv2.warpPerspective(img, transform, img.shape[1::-1])
```

Comment: What is `[1::-1]`mean?

Comment: @tomfriwel In Python list indexing is [begin:end:step], so [1::-1] means from the second element (indexes start at 0) to end, reversed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation